# Having problems with differentiating $y=e^x/x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is it a good idea for me to use the quotient rule in this scenario? How should I go about differentiating this problem?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Tried using the quotient rule?

Comment: Yes it is a good idea to use the quotient rule.

Comment: Did you try the quotient rule?

Comment: Yes this is a homework question. The major thing that was tripping me up was taking the derivative of e^x. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Well, taking the derivative of $e^x$ is really nothing that should trip you.

Comment: First warm up with product rule to differentiate $y= xe^x$. Next use quotient rule in this problem.Differentiation of $e^x$ is easy ( no change) and is the same operation in either case.

Answer (score 1):

The quotient rule works just fine:

Put $f(x) = e^x \implies f'(x) = e^x$.

Put $g(x) = x \implies g'(x) = 1$.

Then, by the quotient rule, we have:
$$y = \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} \implies y' = \dfrac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{(g(x))^2}.$$

Alternatively, you can use the product rule, noting that $\dfrac {e^x}x = e^x\cdot x^{-1}$.  Then $$y = e^xx^{-1} \implies y' = (e^x)'x^{-1} + e^x(x^{-1})'$$

Answer (score 0):

I will only give you a hint on how you can differentiate 
$$
y = \frac{e^x}{x}.
$$
First note that this is a quotient of functions, so one approach would be so use the quotient rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{g(x)^2}.
$$
In your case $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = x$. All that is left for you to do is to find $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

The quotient rule would be a fantastic idea.

Or maybe even more straightforward is the product rule:

$$y'(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\left(e^xx^{-1} \right) = e^x \cdot (-x^{-2}) + (x^{-1}) \cdot e^x = e^x\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}\right).$$